# How can I increase the length of the string returned by object_definition in sqlcmd?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlcmd

I have an sql script that uses `select object_defintion(object_id(...))` to extract the definition from a view.

This script is run with sqlcmd: `sqlcmd -i extract.sql -o %oudir%\extracted.dat`.

Unfortunately, the length of the returned string seems to be truncated so that not the entire view definition is extracted.

Is there a possibility to extend the length of the returned string?

Answer (score 4):

Specify the `-y` [SQLCMD option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) to avoid truncating the value to the 256 character default. `-y0` will not truncate the value but should be used with caution as mentioned in the doc.

Example:

```
sqlcmd -i extract.sql -y0 -o %oudir%\extracted.dat
```